# else condition won't display on bash scripting

Tags: linux, shell-script

Can someone help me on this.

This script being use to monitor multple servers and display its error status from the logs, the same logic I have used on other server but it is working and there is one would not work even though they are identically coded.

What happen here is when status of alarm being extract but the alarm didn't satisfy all the if's condition it won't display the last part which is the No Alarm status under else condition. it display blank. Thanks in advance for helping

```
for ((i=0;i<${#arrPNMIP[@]};++i)); do

ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 ${arrPNMIP[i]} cat /logs/notificationmanager.log |
    grep -i ALARM | grep ${_date}T${_hour} |
    tail -1 > ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=30 ${arrPNMIP[i]} cat /logs/notificationmanager.log |
    grep 'disconnectUnsafe disconnected host' | grep ${_date}T${_hour} |
    tail -1 > ${_dir}DCHU_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt


_count=$(wc -l ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | awk '{print $1}')
_timestamp=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | awk '{print $1}' |
    tail -1 | cut -c 10-13)
_typeR=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep RAISED | wc -l)
_typeC=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep CEASED | wc -l)
_overload=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep -i overload | wc -l)
_sftp=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep -i sftp | wc -l)
_linkbus=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep -i linkbus | wc -l)
_dbconn=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep -i dbconn | wc -l)
_hbmgr=$(cat ${_dir}overload_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt | grep -i hbmgr | wc -l)

_DChostUnsafeCount=$(cat ${_dir}DCHU_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt |
    grep 'disconnectUnsafe disconnected host' | wc -l)
_dcIPhostUnsafe=$(cat ${_dir}DCHU_${arrPNMHOST[i]}.txt |
    grep 'disconnectUnsafe disconnected host' | awk -F " " '{print $8}' |
    cut -c 2-14 )


#echo ""

if (( ${_count[@]} >= 1)) || (( ${_DChostUnsafeCount[@]} >= 1));
then
  if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_overload[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}RAISED ALARM "\
"OVERLOAD at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_sftp[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}RAISED ALARM "\
"SFTP at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_linkbus[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}RAISED ALARM "\
"LINKBUS at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_dbconn[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}RAISED ALARM "\
"DBCONN at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_hbmgr[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}RAISED ALARM "\
"HBMGR at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_DChostUnsafeCount[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_RED}${F_BLACK}Disconnected "\
"Host with IP:${_dcIPhostUnsafe} at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi

  if (( ${_typeC[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_overload[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_YELLOW}${F_BLACK}CEASED ALARM "\
"OVERLOAD at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeC[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_sftp[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_YELLOW}${F_BLACK}CEASED ALARM "\
"SFTP at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeC[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_linkbus[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_YELLOW}${F_BLACK}CEASED ALARM "\
"LINKBUS at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeC[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_dbconn[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_YELLOW}${F_BLACK}CEASED ALARM "\
"DBCONN at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi
  if (( ${_typeC[@]} >= 1)) && (( ${_hbmgr[@]} >= 1 ));
  then
    echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_YELLOW}${F_BLACK}CEASED ALARM "\"
"HBMGR at ${_timestamp}${BG_NC}"
  fi

else
  echo -e "${arrPNMHOST[i]} ${arrPNM[i]}:${BG_GREEN}${F_BLACK}NO ALARM${BG_NC}"
fi
done

=================================================================
sample result display of the script

Event Detection Trigger
VMRVNAPD07 EDT07:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD08 EDT08:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD09 EDT09:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD10 EDT10:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD11 EDT11:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD12 EDT12:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD13 EDT13:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD14 EDT14:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD15 EDT15:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD16 EDT16:NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD28 EDT28:NO ALARM

Personal Notification Manager

Access Manager
VMRVNAPD17 AM01: NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD18 AM02: RAISED ALARM SFTP at 0332

Messaging Server
VMRVNAPD30 MSVM01: NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD31 MSVM02: NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD37 MSVM03: NO ALARM
VMRVNAPD40 MSVM04: NO ALARM
```

Comment: That's a rather big script (for a question here), and relies on external files and such. Could you reduce that to a smaller script with mock input that would still exhibit the problem? It would make it easier for others to reason about it and test it.

Comment: Yes, please post a minimal example that illustrates the problem that you're having.

Comment: With what you are showing, we cannot reproduce your issue. In order to **trace execution** of your script I suggest using the `set +x option` [Debugging Bash scripts](https://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html). Then you'll see what the script is doing and what it's not doing. Another point: you have a lot of **repetitive code** eg: `if (( ${_typeR[@]} >= 1))`. You can shorten and simplify code. Add a nested `if` for example.

Comment: Hi Team,

I have put sample of the display result of the script if you will see "personal notification manager" has no out display it is happened when the scripts detect that there is no alarm on the server. however, it won't display the NO ALARM output.

Comment: Why the strange "let's prefix all our variable names with underscore"?

Comment: Why do you use `[@]` on non-array variables?

Comment: I'm guessing there's something there that matches "ALARM" (and hence gets included in the ...overload... file), but doesn't match any of the specific alarm conditions to search for. IMO it'd be much better to read the ...overload... file line-by-line, checking for recognized errors (e.g. with a `case` statement), with an if-a-line-doesn't-match-any (that'd be `* )` pattern in a `case` statement) that warns of an unknown alarm. Also, all those [UUoCs](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) hurt my soul; please replace e.g. `cat somefile | grep pattern` with `grep pattern somefile`.